# How to add mtext to dimension after already placing it in Autocad?

Tags: text, overriding, autocad

I am trying to edit a linear dimension after it has already been placed, adding mtext. I understand that you can override the text on a linear dimension, but my goal is to be able to stack two numbers on top of each other under one dimension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the escape code `\X` to stack two texts:

```
Upper\XLower
```

Comment: \X is very similar to what I was looking for. But through your answer I discovered \P which works better for my specific situation (since it justifies the linear dimensions along with it).

Comment: There is a static property for this code: `MText.LineBreak`

Answer (score 0):

Probably the Dimension.Prefix property will do the trick here.